# fread segfaults with correct file length and buffer allocation

Tags: c, c++11, file-io, io, fread

I have code that saves a 2D float array into a binary file, and another code that reads the binary file and puts it in a 2D float array.

```
void write2DArrayToBinary(const char* file_name, void** array, size_t len_1D, size_t len_2D, size_t num_bytes_per_elem) {
  FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "wb");
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len_1D; i++) {
    fwrite(array[i], num_bytes_per_elem, len_2D, file);
  }
  fclose(file);
}

void read2DArrayFromBinary(void** array, size_t len_1d, size_t len_2d, size_t num_bytes_per_elem, const char* file_name) {
  FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "rb");
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len_1d; i++) {
    array[i] = malloc(num_bytes_per_elem * len_2d);
    fread(array[i], num_bytes_per_elem, len_2d, file);
  }
  fclose(file);
}
```

The former is inside a .C file and the latter is in a .CC ( c++11 ).
I call the read function like this ( I have omitted irrelevent code ) :

```
this->dilate_weights_prev = (float**)malloc(sizeof(float*) * this->num_layers);
read2DArrayFromBinary((void**)this->dilate_weights_prev, this->num_layers, this->dilate_weights_prev_len, sizeof(float), fileName);
```

I have checked that the `len_1D` and `len_2D` in `write2DArrrayToBinary` and `read2DArrayFromBinary` are the same. Also, I have used gdb, and the read function segfaults on its first iteration.

What do you think cold be causing this?

Comment: @DYZ I have edited for clarification. The write function is called in C and the read function is called in C++.

Comment: Just curious, why do you cast your array to `void**` when it is clearly a `float**`?

Comment: @DYZ just to keep things generic ( I also use this for int arrays ).

Comment: Have you checked if `file` is not NULL? (You must.) Have you checked if `array[i]` is not NULL? (You must.) Both `fopen` and `malloc` can fail.

Comment: you lack definitions for `dilate_weights_prev`, `num_layers` and `dilate_weights_prev_len` and especially how you get the value for the last one.

Comment: @DYZ turns out fopen was returning NULL! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize what I already wrote in the comments: You call several POSIX functions (`fread`, `malloc`, and `fopen`, to name a few) without checking their return values. Any of these functions can fail for a number of reasons. If you want your program to be robust, you should not proceed to the next statement without checking if the previous function call was successful. In particular, both `fopen` and `malloc` can return a NULL. Make sure they don't.